# Why is my delegate method not called in a storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, uistoryboard

I have two `UIViewController`s embedded in a `UINavigationController`. The first view controller has the following source code :

ViewController.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController_2.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <HanselDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TestLabel;

- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"To call the second UIViewController...");
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"idCallSecond" sender:self];
}

-(void)SetFirstLabel {
     NSLog(@"To run the delegate method...");
     _TestLabel.text = @"Hello from the second...";
}
@end
```

The second controller has the following code:

ViewController2.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol HanselDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)SetFirstLabel;

@end

@interface ViewController_2 : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak)id<HanselDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)Button2Click:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController2.m:

```
#import "ViewController_2.h"

@interface ViewController_2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController_2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Button2Click:(id)sender {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(SetFirstLabel)]) {
        NSLog(@"To call the delegate method");
        [self.delegate SetFirstLabel];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

If I press the button in `ViewController2`, the method `SetFirstLabel` doesn't get called. Why is it so? Did I forgot something?

Comment: **#1** most common delegate mistake: forgetting to set the delegate

Comment: Also, methods should **never** start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to set the delegate in ViewController.m

set this in ViewController.m

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"idCallSecond"]) {
        ViewController_2 * vc2 = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc2.delegate = self;
    }
}
```